# How do I move the background image of a DIV based on the scrollbar movement?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been looking into [parallax effects](http://inspiretrends.com/parallax-scrolling-tutorials/) for vertical scrolling on my web page, and after some research, I'm not sure that what I want to do is technically a parallax effect.

From what I've seen, most parallax effects assume you want to be able to scroll indefinitely with many background images rolling by, or with huge images that repeat.

What I want to do is have the background of two DIVs be filled with a background image as the scroll bar reaches the bottom of the page. **Note that I do not want the background images to stretch.** I'm assuming to get the effect I want that these images would have a vertical height bigger than most people's viewport, and then their vertical position would change. When the user's scrollbar is at the top, a certain amount of the background is visible, and then it moves vertically to fill the background space as the user scrolls down.

Please see the image below for a visual explanation of the effect I hope to acheive:

[image]

The height of the veiwport will vary depending on the length of content inside the inner DIV.

My trouble is that if what I am trying to do is not exactly a parallax effect, then I don't know what else to call it, and my attempts to search by describing it keep landing me back at pages offering tutorials on parallax effects. So I've been stumped by a lack of terminology.

If someone could direct me to how I can control the vertical position of the background depending on the scrollbar position, that would be much appreciated. If this can be done with just CSS that would be great, but I'm assuming some Javascript would be required. A jQuery solution would also work for me.

---

**Update:**

After searching using the terms provided in comments, I've got the background image in the outer DIV to almost do what I want with the following code:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
var yPos = $("#outerDiv").height() - ($("#outerDIV").height() * ($(window).scrollTop() / $(window).height()));
document.getElementById('outerDIV').style.backgroundPosition="0px " + yPos + "px";
});
```

It moves the background image in the right direction relative to the scrolling, but what it lacks is constraining that motion to within the viewport. Getting the right proportions based on the viewport and DIV sizes is proving to be just a little beyond my mathematical abilities.

Comment: `background-position` is the CSS property, `scroll` is the event, `scrollTop` is the JavaScript property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out what I want to acheive is possible with no special plugins, just some carefully thought out math. I did use a little jQuery syntax, but I don't think it's strictly necessary.

The code below has copious notes, so hopefully it's largely explanatory. In summary, you just need to find the position of the background image when the scroll would be at the top, and the position it would be if the scroll bar was at the bottom, and then you can use the percentage of the scrollbar's movement to work out where you are between those two points. It's a little tricker than just that, of course, in that you have to account for the difference between the total height of the scroll bar and where your DIV appears on the page and a few other adjustments, but the details of what I did are below.

What I've done here is just for the "outer DIV" that I described in my question. To get a background to move like the "inner DIV" I described, you'd have to modify the code, presumeably by reversing a few parameters. I haven't done that yet, but it seems like a straightforward task.

Hope others find this code useful. If anyone has suggestions on how it can be made more efficient or better, please let me know.

```
function moveBG(){
   // imageHeight is not the total height of the image,
   // it's the vertical amount you want to ensure remains visible no matter what.
   var imageHeight = 300;
   // Get the maximum amount within the DIV that the BG can move vertically.
   var maxYPos = $("#outerDIV").height() - imageHeight;
   // Get the amount of vertical distance from the top of the document to
   // to the top of the DIV.
   var headerHeight = document.getElementById("outerDIV").offsetTop;
   // Calculate the BG Y position for when the scrollbar is at the very top.
   var bgTopPos = $(window).height() - headerHeight - imageHeight;
   // I don't want the image to wander outside of the DIV, so ensure it never
   // goes below zero.
   if (bgTopPos < 0)
   {
      bgTopPos = 0;
   }
   // Calculate the BG Y position when the scrollbar is at the very top.
   var bgBottomPos = $(document).height() - $(window).height() - headerHeight;
   // To prevent the BG image from getting cut off at the top, make sure
   // its position never exceeds the maximum distance from the top of the DIV.
   if (bgBottomPos > maxYPos)
   {
      bgBottomPos = maxYPos;
   }
   // Subtract the top position from the bottom, and you have the spread
   // the BG will travel.
   var totalYSpan = bgBottomPos - bgTopPos;
   // Get the scrollbar position as a "percentage". Note I simply left it as a 
   // value between 0 and 1 instead of converting to a "true" percentage between
   // 0 and 100, 'cause we don't need that in this situation.
   var scrollPercent = ($(window).scrollTop() / ( $(document).height() - $(window).height()));
   // The percentage of spread is added to the top position, and voila!
   // You have your Y position for the BG image.
   var bgYPos = bgTopPos + (Math.round(totalYSpan * scrollPercent));
   // Apply it to the DIV.
   document.getElementById('outerDIV').style.backgroundPosition="0px " + bgYPos + "px";
}
// Place the BG image correctly when opening the page.
$(document).ready(function() {
   moveBG();
});
// Make it update when the scrollbar moves.
$(window).scroll(function () {
   moveBG();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For your requirement, you have to use a **jquery parallax plugin** to guide this activity, my best suggest it to use a [Superscollorama](http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/) and play with the elements as your wish...

As far as your question, Try this example,

```
controller.addTween(
    '#examples-background',
    (new TimelineLite())
    .append([
        TweenMax.fromTo($('#parallax-it-left'), 1, 
        {css:{backgroundPosition:"(0 -54px)"}, immediateRender:true}, 
        {css:{backgroundPosition:"(0 -54px)"}}),
        TweenMax.fromTo($('#parallax-it-right'), 1, 
        {css:{backgroundPosition:"(0 -54px)"}, immediateRender:true}, 
        {css:{backgroundPosition:"(0 54px)"}})
    ]),
1000 // scroll duration of tween
);
```

You serial vice change as far as your wish...

Try practice this plugin, hope that works for you...

http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/

Thanks...

Comment: Thank you for responding. The reason I did not go with *Super Scrollorama* is because it is too feature rich, with too many parameters to learn, too many files and directories, so that it becomes almost like an additional language to learn on top of the Javascript involved. I'm sure it does some very fancy things very well, but I felt in my case it was a bit overkill. Hopefully others will find your suggestion useful, though.